# how to create a define that will check if the compiler supports std::execution?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, c++20

I found that the android NDK still does not support std::execution yet.

I need a code snippet to detect this during compile time to enable alternative code.

Kindly help.

Comment: Does the [`__cpp_lib_parallel_algorithm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) macro not fit your needs?

Comment: @ildjarn feature test macros are a C++20 feature, its hard to imagine having its support and not for C++17's `std::execution`.

Comment: @madhur4127 : I'm not sure what you're getting at. This question is tagged C++20, and Apple Clang (among others) has support for C++20 but not `std::execution`.

Comment: @ildjarn my bad, I kinda assumed that almost all compilers will support `std::execution` if C++20 is enabled. I think OP might also be interested in `__cpp_lib_execution`.

Comment: @ildjarn Forget Apple Clang, even the vanilla Clang (libc++, rather) has no support. D: